# In Spring MVC web application how to retain form SELECT elements between requests?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement a Spring MVC web application without Ajax.

Currently have a form with a set of cascading dropdowns. On change of subsequent select (dropdowns) elements how to retain the item list of previously selected dropdown and also simultaneously clearing the item lists of subsequent dropdown elements and resetting the values of the dropdown elements to `null` or default. At present I'm putting the list items fetched from the database into the `ModelAndView` object. Doing this way the dropdown items are not being retained in the next request. Is it a good practice to put the such cascading dropdown list items in `HttpSession` object? What is the recommended & efficient way to handle such a page flow in Spring MVC?

Following is the Controller request handler method :-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add.do",method=RequestMethod.GET,params="actionMethod=beginAddBldg")
    public ModelAndView beginAddBuilding(@ModelAttribute("addBuildingFormBean") Building building) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addBldg");
        List<Division> lstOfDivisions=buildingService.getDivisions();
        mv.addObject("divisionList", lstOfDivisions);
        return mv;
    }
```

And following is the JSP page code :-

```
<form:form name="addBuildingForm" modelAttribute="addBuildingFormBean" method="POST">
        <form:hidden path="actionMethod"/>
        <form:hidden path="actionForward"/>
        <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="divisionID">
                        Division
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="divisionID" id="divisionID" onchange="getNextListItems(document.addBuildingForm,'getSubdivs','addBldg','/buildings/add.do');">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                        <form:options items="${divisionList}" itemLabel="divisionName" itemValue="divisionID"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="subdivisionID">
                        Subdivision
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="subdivisionID" id="subdivisionID" onchange="getNextListItems(document.addBuildingForm,'getDistrictsList','addBldg','/add.do');">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="districtID">
                        District
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="districtID" id="districtID" onchange="getNextListItems(document.addBuildingForm,'getTaluksList','addBldg','/add.do');">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="talukID">
                        Taluk
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="talukID" id="talukID" onchange="getNextListItems(document.addBuildingForm,'getVillagesList','addBldg','/add.do');">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <form:checkbox path="isTown" id="isTown"/>
                    <form:label path="isTown">
                        List only Towns (villages with population >= 10,000)
                    </form:label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="villageCode">
                        Town/Village
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="villageCode" id="villageCode">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="yearOfConstID">
                        Year of Construction
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="yearOfConstID" id="yearOfConstID">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="buildingTypeID">
                        Type of Building
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="buildingTypeID" id="buildingTypeID">
                        <form:option value="-1">--Select--</form:option>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="buildingName">
                        Name of Building
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="buildingName" id="buildingName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <form:label path="noOfFloors">
                        No. of Floors
                    </form:label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="noOfFloors" id="noOfFloors" maxlength="3"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: You can put your stuff in the session and that's totally fine. Thus you won't have to re-fetch them on every request but they will live for the time of the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them is the session but the previously selected item will not be selected on page refresh unless you actually bind the model i.e. submit the partially completed form on each change.

You can avoid the session and create a method annotated with @ModelAttribute. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods and for any request through that controller the list will be populated. This will not avoid the problem of the wrong item being selected but will avoid the use of the session.

A better method that would fix everything is to make an Ajax call which would simply return an HTML fragment containing the updated `<select/>` i.e. avoiding whole page refresh but you will need to research that.